# How to change SSH password on CentOS?

Tags: ssh

Im using new VPS account with SSH password.

But the password is very simple.

I want to change it, but how?

Answer (score 14):

SSH uses your linux user password.  Simply use the `passwd` command after logging in. It will prompt you to change it.

```
passwd
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change password for your current user, you just need to type

```
passwd
```

If you want to change password of another user, for example user1, you can type this

```
passwd user1
```